# "Or", or "to put it otherwise", which one is better in this paragraph?

Tags: writing

> As Benvensite wrote, the linguistic structure of Greek created the predisposition for the notion “to be” to have a philosophical vocation. **To put it otherwise**, as I said, to assert solemnly, as Parmenides does, that there’re things means admitting that there is what is being, or, more generally, by being, it is. (By Being, It Is, by Nestor Luis Cordero)

I want to know whether “or” could be put in place of “to put it otherwise” to make the sentence more concise?

Comment: Keep the 'or' and scrap the rest of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

**Or** implies an *alternative* option.

**To put it otherwise** implies the *same* thing expressed in different words.

Hence, ***or*** could not *replace* ***to put it otherwise***.
But one could write "Or, to put it otherwise, ..."

Comment: I think "Or" is fine as a synonym for "To put it otherwise"-- I don't see the need to make things wordier than necessary, especially as the rest of the sentence is a rambling mess.

Comment: Actually, there is no logical reason not to start the second sentence at the words "To assert solemnly, as Parmenides does," since the "as I said" aside serves mainly to warn readers that the author is about to repeat himself. The sentence would benefit from more-consistent parallelism, too, and from a general cleanup of the glop in the second half. Doing so produces a sentence along these lines: "To assert solemnly, as Parmenides does, that things exist is to admit that being itself exists, or, more generally, that being, by being, is." See how much clearer that is?

Comment: Thank you! As an aside, I think your rewording of the sentence entails a tangible knowledge of Parmenides'philosophy. You seem to hold a coherent view of What Parmenides mean by his short fragment.